# AudioManager PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE on kindle

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, kindle-fire

We deployed our app on amazon and sometimes we are getting `null` when retrieving the audio output sample rate from the audio manager on a kindle.

Our code is (more or less as follows:

```java
AudioManager audioService = (AudioManager) myApp.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)

int sampleRate = Integer.parseInt(audioService.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
```

Our app sometimes crashes when parsing - complaining about NumberFormatException originating from a null value it got.

Are there some known issues with kindle or amazon devices in this area ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this too on KITKAT API 19(LG L65 rooted) and use permission.RECORD_AUDIO . But these constants add API 17! But I get null!

```
getProperty("PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER");
getProperty("PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE");
```

return null.

> A string representing the associated value for that property key, or
>   null if there is no value for that key.

Usually if get null you must use(most popular android values):

```
FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 256 
DEFAULT_SAMPLING_RATE = 44100
```

Example there https://github.com/ReadyTalk/webrtc/blob/master/webrtc/modules/audio_device/android/java/src/org/webrtc/voiceengine/AudioManagerAndroid.java

Answer (score 0):

[Currently Amazon Kindles support Android 4.1 or higher](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201245160).

According to the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE), `PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE` was added in Android [API Level 17, aka Android 4.2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).

It seems like `PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE` may not be supported in Amazon Kindles because it may be running an outdated version of Android (4.1 < 4.2).

Try updating your Kindles' Android!

Answer (score 0):

THE "solution":

```
val AudioManager.outputFramesPerBuffer: Int
    get() = getProperty(PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)
        ?.asInt().takeUnless { it == 0 } ?: 256

val AudioManager.outputSampleRate: Int
    get() = getProperty(PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE)
        ?.asInt().takeUnless { it == 0 } ?: 44100
```